# Definir rango de tiempo

Tags: c#

Tengo definido tres diferentes horarios de 8 a 16, de 16 a 23:30 y de 23:30 a 8. Para poder tener la visualización por pantalla para el usuario he tomado la hora del servidor. 
Ahora tengo el problema de como mostrar en pantalla el tipo de horario que se encuentra actualmente.

```
  HoraInicio.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("8:00:00");
  HoraFin.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse("16:00:00");
```

He definido el rango pero como podría definirlo para mostrarlo por pantalla

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Qué control escoger para mostrar horas? Por otro lado ¿No es un poco injusto que el horario de mañanas sea de 8h, el de tardes 7:30 y el de noches 8:30?

Comment: Te refieres a que dependiendo de la hora actual del sistema, muestre por ejemplo Mañana, Tarde o Noche?

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el horario actual podrías utilizar **DateTime.Now**:

```
DateTime horarioActual = DateTime.Now;
```

Ahora entiendo que según el horario actual querés mostrar o realizar acciones con los horarios de inicio y fin que corresponden, entonces para eso podes comparar el horario actual con los intervalos horarios que estableciste utilizando **TimeOfDay**.

```
if (horarioActual.TimeOfDay >= DateTime.Parse("8:00:00").TimeOfDay 
    && horarioActual.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Parse("16:00:00").TimeOfDay) {
       //El horario actual esta dentro del rango mañana, establezco horario inicio y fin
       HoraInicio.MinDate = DateTime.Parse("8:00:00");
       HoraFin.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse("16:00:00");
       // o las acciones que quiera realizar..
    }
```

Y así comparas los demás intervalos (tarde y noche).

Saludos.